# Exchange online retention policy not sure which policy is active

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365, exchange-2013

We have Microsoft Online Exchange Business Plan One, and by default my retention policy is set to "Default MRM Policy". This policy is shown below and in this image:

[image]

> ### Default MRM Policy
>
> This policy contains the following retention tags
>
> 1 Month Delete
> 1 Week Delete
> 1 Year Delete
> 5 Year Delete
> 6 Month Delete
> Default 2 year move to archive
> Junk Email
> Never Delete
> Personal 1 year move to archive
> Personal 5 year move to archive
> Personal never move to archive
> Recoverable Items 14 days move to archive

From this I am not able to make out which retention policy is applicable (1 week, 1 month, 1 year, etc.)

I would appreciate any clarification on this. I have checked different tutorials but they don’t show clearly which policy tag is active.

Answer (score 0):

You only have 1 policy that includes multiple tags in the policy.

So - all those tags are active.  They all do different things.  They are mix of mailbox and personal tags.  mailbox tags can be assigned from the server, such as the Archive and Deleted items (which you don't have b/c you can't set it unless you create or re-name the default policy).  Personal tags are assigned by the user in Outlook / OWA and no mailboxes/folders have them applied by default.